# How to run program with variable command line arguments?

Tags: command-line, autoit

I have the following script:

```
For $alpha = 1 to 10
 For $beta = 1 to 10
  Run('"C:\Users\MyProg.exe ' & alpha/10 & ' ' & beta/10 & ' 200 2 0.5'
  ;some other actions follow
 Next
Next
```

I have checked many times that the string is well-formed, thus I have no idea why the script wouldn't run the program. Could you help me please?

Comment: Missing a closing " and ) for a start?

Comment: Have you tried assign your run statement in the loops to a variable first and just controlled via `ConsoleWrite(...)` whether the statements are all concatenated properly and can be run each on its own on a command line?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the ending `'` with `"')` and use proper variable names including the `$`... like `$alpha` instead of just `alpha`. Your syntax check in SciTE should have told you.

```
For $alpha = 1 to 10
    For $beta = 1 to 10
        Run('"C:\Users\MyProg.exe ' & $alpha/10 & ' ' & $beta/10 & ' 200 2 0.5"')
        ;some other actions follow
    Next
Next
```